# why i have been blocked from asking questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

i asked a two questions on superuser community one is with -5 votes and another is with +2 votes,and i even voted to delete my question to why am i blocked from asking question further?

please refer my questions and answer my query am i asked anything wrong and not related to community,i deleted my second question after it has been suggested it's not constructive

[question 1](https://superuser.com/questions/458949/how-can-you-improve-accessibility-in-visual-studio-for-visually-impaired-people)

Comment: there are 2 deleted questions with votes -5 and -4. There's a deleted answer with -1. None of your posts are correctly formatted and quite poor language wise. You don't punctuate your posts. You don't use proper capitalization. Even after editing, it's the same crap. Low quality filter says hello.

Comment: @Sathya i agree why can't the community give me chance to correct myself with the next post?am i temporarily blocked from asking question,as i deleted my posts with -5 and -4 votes why this ban exists?

Comment: the community has given you enough chances, and all you have done is lip service. This question itself is a prime example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 deleted questions with votes -5 and -4. There's a deleted answer with -1. None of your posts are correctly formatted and quite poor language wise. You don't punctuate your posts. You don't use proper capitalization. Even after editing you haven't improved.

The automated low-quality filters have kicked in, and deleted questions are *not* exempt. You still have a chance to edit your posts. And answer some questions, hopefully this time without plagiarizing and with proper punctuation and formatting.

Read

- [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)
- [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)